# runtime error when try to read fetchrequest<>

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I want to get data form coredata ,and show it in Charts,
there is a runtime error at the code in init func when app is loaded:

let x=self.marks.wrappedValue.count

the error message is :Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

the whole code is following:

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts
import CoreData

struct CareDetails: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    let timeSpan=["day","week","month","year"]

    let care:Care
    var marks:FetchRequest<Mark>
    @State private var timeSpanIndex = 0
    @State private var showSheet  = false
    private var  sessions:[Int]=[]
    private var  accuracy:[Double]=[]
    init(care:Care){
        self.care=care
        self.marks = FetchRequest(entity:Mark.entity(),
                                                sortDescriptors: [],
                                                predicate: NSPredicate(format:"care_id == %@",care.id!.uuidString))


        let x=self.marks.wrappedValue.count





    }
    var body: some View {

            VStack{

                        Picker(selection: $timeSpanIndex, label: Text("timeSpan")) {
                            ForEach(0..<timeSpan.count,id:\.self){ idx in
                                Text(self.timeSpan[idx])
                            }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                        .padding()

                LineChartViewSwiftUI(dataLabel: self.care.unit!,sessions: self.sessions,accuracy: self.accuracy)



                 Form{
                    Section{
                        List{
                            NavigationLink(destination:
                            CareDetailsList(marks: self.marks)
                                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.context)
                            ){

                                Text("显示所有数据")

                            }
                        }

                    }
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                }
            .padding()

            }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It hasn't been evaluated yet. It resolves when `update()` gets called by your view's `body` function. Try structuring it slightly differently and using it directly in `body`.

```swift
struct CareView: View {
    let care: Care
    @FetchRequest var marks: FetchedResult<Mark>

    @State private var timeSpanIndex = 0
    @State private var showSheet  = false

    init(care: Care) {
        self.care = care
        self._marks = FetchRequest(...) // set up as before now. note the `_` though!
    }

    var body: some View {
        // make sure you can ID each `Mark` by something
        ForEach(marks, id: \.id) { mark in
            // create your `MarkView` here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a newer for swift,what's difference between self.marks and self._marks?

Comment: In this new structure, `@FetchRequests` is a property wrapper, a new feature in Swift 5.1. They're basically structs (typically) that wrap an underlying value and transform it or provide additional functionality around it. When you call `self.marks`, there is syntactic sugar that lets you directly manipulate the _wrapped_ value. When you call `self._marks`, you are manipulating the property wrapper struct/class itself.